# Javascript array of object group by multiple values by summing up

Tags: javascript

```
[ 
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "4" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "3", Value2: "7" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "2" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "2", Value2: "1" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "3" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "4", Value2: "8" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "5", Value2: "1" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }
]
```

Hi, i have a this Array of objects and i am expecting the below format. 
I wants to get result by adding all data for value1, value2 (It can be dynamic or may be more)
Grouping by Phase.

I am coding in javascript but, result is not coming proper.

```
[ 
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "15", Value2: "14" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "11", Value2: "13" }
]
```

I can't find any lodash function achive this. 
Can it be done with or without using lodash?

Comment: I didn't understand you properly, do you want to sort the array by ascending order by "Phase"?

Comment: You can do it just using the native array `reduce` method. But Stack Overflow isn't for people to write code for you given a description of the problem - it's for helping you overcome problems you've encountered while writing the solution yourself.

Comment: @VaheYavrumian  i am not trying to sort. i wants to get agreegated result by Phrase by summing value1 and value2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

this is not so generic code, but can help you to write the code further

```js
x = [ 
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "4" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "3", Value2: "7" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "5", Value2: "2" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: "2", Value2: "1" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "3" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "4", Value2: "8" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "5", Value2: "1" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }
];

var ph1Val1 = 0; var ph1Val2 = 0; var ph2Val1 = 0; var ph2Val2 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
     if(x[i].Phase == "Phase 1"){
            var v1 = x[i].Value1;
            var v2 = x[i].Value2;
            ph1Val1 = ph1Val1 + parseInt(v1);
            ph1Val2 = ph1Val2 + parseInt(v2);
     }
     if(x[i].Phase == "Phase 2"){
        var p2v1 = x[i].Value1;
        var p2v2 = x[i].Value2;
        ph2Val1 = ph2Val1 + parseInt(p2v1);
          ph2Val2 = ph2Val2 + parseInt(p2v2);
 }
}


var obj1 = { Phase: "Phase 1",Value1: ph1Val1, Value2: ph1Val2 };
var obj2 = { Phase: "Phase 2",Value1: ph2Val1, Value2: ph2Val2 };
var y = [];
y.push(obj1);
y.push(obj2);

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take `Phase` out of the object and group by this value and take the rest for summing.

```js
var data = [{ Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "4" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "3", Value2: "7" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "2" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "2", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "3" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "4", Value2: "8" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "5", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { Phase, ...o }) => {
        if (!r[Phase]) r[Phase] = { Phase };
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[Phase][k] = (r[Phase][k] || 0) + +v);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like this way too:

```js
var k = [{ Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "4" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "3", Value2: "7" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "5", Value2: "2" }, { Phase: "Phase 1", Value1: "2", Value2: "1", different:"7" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "3" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "4", Value2: "8" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "5", Value2: "1" }, { Phase: "Phase 2", Value1: "1", Value2: "1" }];

result=k.reduce((acc, {Phase, ...rest})=>{
 presentElement = acc.find(val=>val.Phase==Phase);
 if(presentElement){
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key,val])=>{
    presentElement[key] =  Number(presentElement[key] || 0) + Number(val);
  })} else {
   acc.push({Phase, ...rest});
  }
   return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```